# Give a general class to which a specific $4 \times 4$ special orthogonal matrix belongs

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

In equation (62) of their [recent publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05336), "Separable Decompositions of Bipartite Mixed States", Li and Qiao present the matrix $Q \in \mbox{SO}(4)$,

\begin{equation}
Q=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{equation}

We see that all the entries of the matrix have the same absolute value 
($\frac{1}{2}$), and in the last row and column, all the entries (for probabilistic reasons) are positive. I would be interested in other $4 \times 4$ special orthogonal matrices with these properties, and more broadly still in $n \times n$ special orthogonal counterparts. (I have an application in mind with $n=11$.)

Comment: See [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix). But the order of a Hadamard matrix must be $1$, $2$ or a multiple of $4$, so $n=11$ won't work.

Comment: So, $Q$ is itself a Hadamard matrix? Is it some (harmless) permutation of the $H_4$ given in the Wikipedia reference. The positivity of the last (alternatively, first) row and column is important for probabilistic reasons in the Li-Qiao scheme.

Comment: $2Q$ is Hadamard.  Interchange the first and last columns, and the first and last rows.  There is, up to row and column permutations and multiplying rows and columns by $-1$, only one $4 \times 4$ Hadamard matrix.

Comment: I generated an $8 \times 8$ Hadamard matrix, but its product with its transpose is not proportional to the identity matrix, so my quest for orthogonality is not fulfilled.

Comment: Perhaps, Paul, you would like to share your remarkable $8\times8$matrix with us.

Comment: Gerry Myerson: As i explain in my recent posting https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351790/are-n-times-n-special-orthogonal-matrices-all-the-entries-of-which-have-the my "remarkable $8 \times 8$ matrix" stemmed from an arithmetic  miscoding of mine. My apologies to the community!

Comment: I take it this is your way of retracting your comment in which you claimed to have constructed such a matrix.